# Limit max length of tag in Angular ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

Having `ng-select` component-> https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/tags (Tags without dropdown panel
)

I want to know if there is something similar to `<input maxlength="255">`. Because if I try `maxlength`, or `size`, it does not work.

It would be desirable if after the character 255 the insertion of additional characters would be interrupted, like in `<input>`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-select doesn't seem to support that yet, but you can do something like:

```
 <ng-select 
...
[addTag]="addTagFn">
</ng-select>

addTagFn = (term) => {
    if (// check here if length of term matches 255 or less) {
        return term;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass attributes to the underlying input element via inputAttrs

```
 <ng-select 
...
  [inputAttrs]="{maxlength: '255'}">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the css side if you want to limit the size of the selected tag or chips  in the ng select
you can use the following code.

```
::ng-deep .ng-value-label {
    max-width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```